# fscanf with character classes

Tags: c

Say I have a file dog.txt

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

I can read from the file like this

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  char str[10];
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("dog.txt", "r");
  fscanf(fp, "%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]", str);
  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}
```

and the program will output `T`. However instead of listing all the letters, can I utilize the POSIX Character Classes, something like `[:upper:]` ?

Comment: No, you can't. Even trying to simulate it with `[A-Z]` leads to implementation defined behavior (sane standard libraries do what you'd expect, but one that interpreted `A-Z` as meaning to accept only 'A', '-' and 'Z' would be allowed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no portable way to do it.  Some implementations allow you to use character ranges like `%[A-Z]`, but that's not guaranteed by the C standard.  C99 §7.19.6.2/12 says this about the `[` conversion specifier (emphasis added):

> The conversion specifier includes all subsequent characters in the `format` string, up to and including the matching right bracket (`]`). The characters between the brackets (the *scanlist*) compose the scanset, unless the character after the left bracket is a circumflex (`^`), in which case the scanset contains all characters that do not appear in the scanlist between the circumflex and the right bracket. If the conversion specifier begins with `[]` or `[^]`, the right bracket character is in the scanlist and the next following right bracket character is the matching right bracket that ends the specification; otherwise the first following right bracket character is the one that ends the specification. **If a `-` character is in the scanlist and is not the first, nor the second where the first character is a `^`, nor the last character, the behavior is implementation-defined.**

The [POSIX.1-2008 description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) has almost identical wording (and even defers to the ISO C standard in case of accidental conflict), so there are no additional guarantees in this case when using a POSIX system.

Comment: @svnpenn: larsmans cited the POSIX standard, I cited the C language standard.  The C standard to be more authoritative than POSIX.

Comment: @svnpenn: it cites the C standard. I assumed you're in a POSIX environment since you mentioned POSIX character classes.

Comment: In a POSIX environment, the POSIX standard is more authorative. The C standard is just more widely applicable.

Comment: @svnpenn: No, not if you want portable code.  GNU's C library implementation (glibc) supports the `%[A-Z]` notation (see the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf), so if you want to limit yourself to glibc, you can use it.  I don't know which other C libraries do/do not support it.

Comment: I think you'll find most Unix-heritage systems will support variations on the `[A-Z]`, `[a-z]`, `[0-9]` ranges as 'implementation defined' extensions.  That's why the standards both say that if `-` appears as other than the first or last character, the behaviour is implementation defined.  The standards would be cautious about specifying that behaviour because of EBCDIC, and because of issues like `[:alpha:]` covering many more characters than `[A-Za-z]` in most code sets.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. This is what you can do with `[]`:

> The conversion specification includes all subsequent bytes in the *format* string up to and including the matching <right-square-bracket> ('`]`'). The bytes between the square brackets (the *scanlist*) comprise the scanset, unless the byte after the <left-square-bracket> is a <circumflex> ('`^`'), in which case the scanset contains all bytes that do not appear in the scanlist between the  and the <right-square-bracket>. If the conversion specification begins with "`[]`" or "`[^]`" , the <right-square-bracket> is included in the scanlist and the next <right-square-bracket> is the matching <right-square-bracket> that ends the conversion specification; otherwise, the first <right-square-bracket> is the one that ends the conversion specification. If a '`-`' is in the scanlist and is not the first character, nor the second where the first character is a '`^`' , nor the last character, the behavior is implementation-defined.

([POSIX standard for `scanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html). The C standard has similar wording, see Adam Rosenfield's answer.)

So, depending on the implementation, you might be able to do `fscanf(fp, "%[A-Z]", str)`, but there's no guarantee that that will work on any POSIX system. In any case, `[:upper:]` is the same as `[:epru]`.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler, hadn't even noticed the `<>` parts not displaying

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fscanf(fp, "%[A-Z]", str);
```