# Scansets in sscanf with string delimiters

Tags: c, parsing, format, scanf

I have an ASCII string in the form of:

```
00001\x02This is a string\x030000100001\x021.0\x03\x021.0\x03\x021.0\x03\x021.0\x03001
```

In descriptive terms, it is a string with a 5 digit leading zeroes integer, a string encapsulated by the STX and ETX ASCII characters, 2 more 5 digit leading zeroes integers, 4 floating point values encapsulated by STX and ETX ASCII characters followed by a 3 digit leading zeroes integer. I am trying to use sscanf to parse the string. It is not behaving as it should. I am using the following format string:

```
"%5hu\x02%[0-9a-zA-Z _-]s\x03%5hu%05hu\x02%lf\x03\x02%lf\x03\x02%lf\x03\x02%lf\x03%3hhu"
```

I have tried changing the scanset to different values including `[^\x03]`. I have also tried adding and removing length specifiers. I am pretty sure it is the scanset that is causing the problem. I am wondering if it is having a hard time with the STX and ETX character literals. Anyone have an idea why this isn't working? Or a better alternative using pure C89? Thanks.

For those wanting the full code to test:

```
unsigned short one;
char two[32];
unsigned short three, four;
double five, six, seven, eight;
unsigned char nine;
char temp[] = "00001\x02This is a string\x03""0000100002\x02""1.1\x03\x02""2.2\x03\x02""3.3\x03\x02""4.5\x03""003";
sscanf(temp, "%5hu\x02%[-0-9a-zA-Z _]s\x03%5hu%05hu\x02%lf\x03\x02%lf\x03\x02%lf\x03\x02%lf\x03%3hhu",
       &one, two, &three, &four, &five, &six, &seven, &eight, &nine);
```

Comment: Watch out: octal constants are limited to at most 3 digits after the backslash, but hex constants are not limited to two or three hexadecimal digits, so `\x0300000100001` is all a single character. I'm not sure whether that's part of your problem or not.

Comment: Also, note that a scanset stands on its own; it is not a qualifier to the `s` conversion specifier. Your format string looks for an actual `s` in the data after what is matched by the scanset.

Comment: Edited to provide full code sample. I am aware of the hex escape problem. In the above example, I broke the string up to prevent the hex escape from using too many characters. I thought the `s` convention was optional. I tested without it and got the same results (or equally bad results).

Comment: See my working code adapted from your original format string (by dropping the s and splitting), and a data string equivalent to your original one (all numbers are 1s instead of varying).  You don't show a test for the return value from `sscanf()`.  Is there any danger that your `sscanf()` does not recognize `%hhu`, for example?  It was added to C99, but the Microsoft compiler is a C89 compiler, not a C99 compiler, for example.  Which platform are you on? Which C compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I can't immediately see why it doesn't work, though I would break it down into a a single string and make it longer and longer until it fails.

Personally, I would parse this with `strtok` (on the boundaries encapsulated by STX and ETX) then use `scanf` to read in the specific floats and integers.

Comment: Never figured out the problem, so I ended up parsing the string into smaller strings using `strtok` and scanning those value in. Not as elegant or efficient as a single `sscanf` call, but at some point, you just have to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out: octal constants are limited to at most 3 digits after the backslash, but hex constants are not limited to two or three hexadecimal digits, so `\x0300000100001` is all a single character.

GCC warned me:

```
ssss.c:6:1: error: hex escape sequence out of range [-Werror]
 "00001\x02This is a string\x030000100001\x021.0\x03\x021.0\x03\x021.0\x03\x021.0\x03001";
 ^
ssss.c:6:1: error: hex escape sequence out of range [-Werror]
```

(In the light of the edit to the question, you're already aware of this issue.)

Also, note that a scanset stands on its own; it is not a qualifier to the `s` conversion specifier. Your format string looks for an actual s in the data after what is matched by the scanset, and will never find one since the scanset eats any s's before the literal match.  This is your actual problem; remove the `s` after the `%[0-9a-zA-Z _-]` scanset.

This code works.  Note the judicious breaking up of the `data` string so that the hex constants are terminated where you want them terminated.  The split in the format string simplifies presentation.  C joins together two adjacent string literals, which is extremely useful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char const data[] =
        "00001\x02This is a string\x03" "0000100001\x02" "1.0\x03\x02"
        "1.0\x03\x02" "1.0\x03\x02" "1.0\x03" "001";
    char const format[] =
        "%5hu\x02%[0-9a-zA-Z _-]\x03%5hu%05hu\x02%lf\x03\x02%lf\x03\x02"
        "%lf\x03\x02%lf\x03%3hhu";

    unsigned short i1;
    char s2[20];
    unsigned short i3;
    unsigned short i4;
    double d5;
    double d6;
    double d7;
    double d8;
    unsigned char i9;
    int rc;

    if ((rc = sscanf(data, format, &i1, s2, &i3, &i4, &d5, &d6, &d7, &d8, &i9)) != 9)
        printf("sscanf failed - %d conversions\n", rc);
    else
        printf("i1 = %d; s2 = [%s]; i3 = %d; i4 = %d; d5 = %f;\n"
               "d6 = %f; d7 = %f; d8 = %f; i9 = %d\n",
               i1, s2, i3, i4, d5, d6, d7, d8, i9);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
i1 = 1; s2 = [This is a string]; i3 = 1; i4 = 1; d5 = 1.000000;
d6 = 1.000000; d7 = 1.000000; d8 = 1.000000; i9 = 1
```

---

I added this code before the `return 0` in `main()`.  This has no `s` after the scanset; when I left the `s` in place, `sscanf()` returned the value 2, not 9.

```
    unsigned short one;
    char two[32];
    unsigned short three, four;
    double five, six, seven, eight;
    unsigned char nine;
    char temp[] = "00001\x02This is a string\x03""0000100002\x02""1.1\x03\x02""2.2\x03\x02""3.3\x03\x02""4.5\x03""003";
    if ((rc = sscanf(temp, "%5hu\x02%[-0-9a-zA-Z _]\x03%5hu%05hu\x02%lf\x03\x02%lf\x03\x02%lf\x03\x02%lf\x03%3hhu",
           &one, two, &three, &four, &five, &six, &seven, &eight, &nine)) != 9)
        printf("sscanf failed - %d conversions\n", rc);
    else
        printf("i1 = %d; s2 = [%s]; i3 = %d; i4 = %d; d5 = %f;\n"
               "d6 = %f; d7 = %f; d8 = %f; i9 = %d\n",
               one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine);
```

The combined program output was:

```
i1 = 1; s2 = [This is a string]; i3 = 1; i4 = 1; d5 = 1.000000;
d6 = 1.000000; d7 = 1.000000; d8 = 1.000000; i9 = 1
i1 = 1; s2 = [This is a string]; i3 = 1; i4 = 2; d5 = 1.100000;
d6 = 2.200000; d7 = 3.300000; d8 = 4.500000; i9 = 3
```

Testing on Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks with GCC 4.8.2.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and no dice. I can only get the first item to scan and convert. So, it must have a problem with the scanset or the STX/ETX characters. I am using a supposedly ANSI C89 compatible compiler from Microchip that is based on GCC.

Comment: Given the feedback you've given, I think the problem is in your C library (rather than the compiler per se, or in your program code).  Note that the `%hhu` conversion is not valid in C89; it was added in C99. (The workaround is to read the value into an `unsigned short` with the `%hu` conversion specification, and then range-validate and assign that value to your `unsigned char` variable.)  AFAICR, the other conversion specifications should all be valid in C89.

Comment: I am beginning to agree about this implementation of the standard C libraries. I did try changing the `%hhu` to just `%hu` but as it is not getting past the scanset, I don't think that is the issue (yet?).

Comment: At this stage, you need to look hard at the documentation for the compiler and library. There really isn't much anyone without the exact same compiler and libraries can do to help you at this point. Consider adding that information to the question. It is possible that the system does not implement scansets. Try changing the data string (for testing only) so there's a space after the string, and replace the scanset with `%s`. Run that and see if it works. It should, or should work better. If it does, then we can point finger firmly at the implementation/library; it doesn't support scansets.

Comment: Another thought; maybe you can replace all the control characters (`\x02` and `\x03`) with blanks before you parse the data with `sscanf()`?  Or make a copy of the data and replace the control characters in the copy. You could check that the correct control characters are in the data in the right sequence as you do the copying.  This may get you around your apparently defective `sscanf()` implementation.  Document (carefully) why you do what you do — they might fix the problem in a later version of the compiler.  Include that in comments in the source near this code, not just in the VCS.

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier is too easily messed.  Consider breaking it up (easier to understand and maintain) and check results

```
#define Int5 "%5hu"
// Note:  no 0 ^

#define STX  "\x02"
#define ETX  "\x03"
// Could use hexadecimal constants here as the string is broken up.

#define EncStr STX "%31[0-9a-zA-Z _-]" ETX
// Note:                        no s ^   (@Jonathan comment s is not part of %[]
// String limit      ^

#define FP    STX "%lf" ETX
#define Int3  "%3hhu"

if (9 == sscanf(temp, Int5 EncStr Int5 Int5 FP FP FP FP Int3, 
    &one, two, &three, &four, &five, &six, &seven, &eight, &nine)) Success();
```

Note: `temp` need to be broken up for hexadecimal clarity or use octal constants

```
char temp[]  = "00001\x02This is a string\x03" "0000100001\x02" "1.0\x03\x02" 
     "1.0\x03\x02" "1.0\x03\x02" "1.0\x03" "001";
char temp[]  = "00001\002This is a string\0030000100001\0021.0\003\0021.0\003\0021.0\003\0021.0\003001";
```

Comment: So, I copied and pasted your code and tried again and it was the same as for Jonathan's code below. It will only parse the first integer. So, something is not happy with the scanset. I may have to rethink my approach and do it with `strtok` or a more manual process as suggested by abligh. Shame because scanf is such a powerful function.

Comment: @Psyfun 1) Did you use one of the 2 `temp` above?  2) Did you use `"%31[0-9a-zA-Z _-]"` or something else?

Comment: @Psyfun I suspect a compiler problem with `-`.  Try `"%31[0-9a-zA-Z _]"` (no final -).  (You are using ASCII?)  Maybe try `"%31[ -~]"`

Comment: @Psyfun A _scanlist_ using the `-` for a range is not standard. "If a - character is in the scanlist and is not the first, nor the second where the first character is a ^, nor the last character, the behavior is implementation-defined"  Further info: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114073/fscanf-with-character-classes/13114106#13114106  Suggest `"%31[^\003]"`.

Comment: I used the broken out temp version with the hex escapse. I will try again with the octals, but I am pretty sure this is working fine because I can see individual character codes for each character in the array. I knew about `-` being implementation dependent and have tried it at the beginning and at the end. I will try removing it altogether. I did try `%[\x03]` and that didn't work either, but may have been other problems at the time. I may have still had the string qualifier `s` in there.

Comment: @Psyfun My suggestion was for `"%31[^\003]"`, not `%[\x03]`.  Note the `^`

Answer (score 1):

So, I have determined that scanset is broken in this version of the C runtime libraries. Here is code that works and doesn't work:

```
unsigned short one;
char two[32];
unsigned short three, four;
double five, six, seven, eight;
unsigned char nine;
int rc1, rc2;

char temp[] = "00001\x02string\x03""0000100002\x02""1.1\x03\x02""2.2\x03\x02""3.3\x03\x02""4.5\x03""003";

char format1[] = "%5hu\x02%[a-z]\x03%5hu%5hu\x02%lf\x03\x02%lf\x03\x02%lf\x03\x02%lf\x03%3hhu";
char format2[] = "%5hu\x02%s\x03%5hu%5hu\x02%lf\x03\x02%lf\x03\x02%lf\x03\x02%lf\x03%3hhu";

rc1 = sscanf(temp, format1, &one, two, &three, &four, &five, &six, &seven, &eight, &nine);   
rc2 = sscanf(temp, format2, &one, two, &three, &four, &five, &six, &seven, &eight, &nine);
```

In the above code, `rc1` returns 1 item successfully scanned and `rc2` returns showing 9 items successfully scanned. So, the conclusion that I have made is that scansets do not work properly with this hardware/software combination. Anyone have any other thoughts or conclusions? Thanks for all the help. I didn't award anyone a solution, but did give points for helpful answers.